# Need assistance to write query to get top number in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table have following columns, (copy to create test table)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[PDNApprovalDetail](
    [PDNApprovalMasterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PDNMasterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PDNApprovalDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentToApproveID] [int] NULL,
    [RulesID] [int] NULL,
    [RuleSignatureTypeID] [smallint] NULL,
    [SignatureTypeID] [smallint] NULL,
    [ApprovalOrder] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PDNApprovalDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PDNApprovalDetailID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- use this insert statement

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PDNApprovalDetail]
           ([PDNApprovalMasterID]
           ,[PDNMasterID]
           ,[DocumentToApproveID]
           ,[RulesID]
           ,[RuleSignatureTypeID]
           ,[SignatureTypeID]
           ,[ApprovalOrder])
     VALUES
           (136
           ,125
           ,7
           ,2
           ,1
           ,0
           ,1)
```

data in my table may look like this (copy and paste to insert query)

```
136,    125,    7,  2,  1,  0,  1
135,    125,    7,  2,  1,  1,  1
136,    125,    7,  2,  1,  1,  1
135,    125,    7,  2,  0,  0,  1
137,    126,    7,  2,  1,  0,  1
137,    126,    7,  2,  1,  0,  1
139,    126,    7,  2,  0,  1,  1
139,    126,    7,  2,  0,  1,  1
138,    127,    7,  2,  1,  1,  1
140,    127,    7,  2,  0,  0,  1
140,    127,    7,  2,  0,  0,  1
```

i want the out put of query by grouping and getting only rows with MAX PDNApprovalMasterID, for group of 125 PDNMasterID, result should not contain rows with ID 135 for group 125 and so on, 
for group of 126 only row with MAX PDNApprovalMasterID 139, 137 should not be there, PDNMasterID 127 result row should contain 140 and should not contain 138

Look at query how to get sum of rest of columns, this is what im trying but not getting right results

```
SELECT DISTINCT pa.PDNMasterID, pa.DocumentToApproveID, pa.PDNApprovalMasterID
    , SUM(CASE WHEN pa.SignatureTypeID = pa.RuleSignatureTypeID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Approved]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN pa.SignatureTypeID != pa.RuleSignatureTypeID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Unapproved]
    , COUNT(*) AS RuleCount
    FROM dbo.PDNApprovalDetail pa
    WHERE pa.[DocumentToApproveID] = 7
    group by pa.PDNMasterID, pa.DocumentToApproveID, pa.PDNApprovalMasterID
    having pa.PDNApprovalMasterID = MAX(pa.PDNApprovalMasterID)
```

result of above query, its contains 135 PDNApprovalMasterID row which should not be there

```
PDNMasterID DocumentToApproveID PDNApprovalMasterID Approved Unapproved RuleCount
125                 7                   135             2         0         2
125                 7                   136             1         1         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `max` to `select statement`

```
SELECT pa.PDNMasterID, pa.DocumentToApproveID, MAX(pa.PDNApprovalMasterID)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN pa.SignatureTypeID = pa.RuleSignatureTypeID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Approved]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN pa.SignatureTypeID != pa.RuleSignatureTypeID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Unapproved]
    , COUNT(*) AS RuleCount
    FROM dbo.PDNApprovalDetail pa
    WHERE pa.[DocumentToApproveID] = 7  
    and pa.PDNApprovalMasterID = (select MAX(pa1.PDNApprovalMasterID)
                                  from  dbo.PDNApprovalDetail pa1 
                                  where pa.PDNMasterID = pa1.PDNMasterID
                                   and pa.DocumentToApproveID = pa1.DocumentToApproveID
                                  ) 
    group by pa.PDNMasterID, pa.DocumentToApproveID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15738/5/0) DEMO

Comment: i have been try, but not working, i also try top 1 but failed

Comment: Does It return the same result?

Comment: @IrfanUllah - You say you tried Parado's answer but it's not working, it worked for me when I tested it. How is it "not working" for you, please describe the problem.

Comment: it shows row ID 136 but see last columns it also includes sum from row ID 135

Comment: result value of column RuleCount in query is 4 because it also includes row 135 it should be 2(value from only row 136), same case with column Approved and Unapproved their sum includes also value from row 135

Comment: thanks, do you recommend that it will work efficiently with huge data?

Comment: Maybe it will be problem. You have to test it, and You see. Don't forget about indexes.